# Multiple elongations in English Dataset

Tags: computational-linguistics

I am studying different research works in Authorship analysis from English data set. I have some features which can be a great tool for authorship analysis.

Some of the common features are:

1. Total characters C
2. Total letters/ C
3. Total digits/ C
4. Total white-spaces/ C
5. Total tab spaces/ C
6. Total elongations
7. Total multiple elongations
8. Total diacritics
9. Total special characters/C 
   10.Total individual letters/ C

Elongations is extending a word. For example, manyyyyyy is an example of elongations. But I want to know what is the example of multiple elongations?

Can anyone enlighten me providing some examples on multiple elongations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is a word that has more than one element elongated. E.g.: maaaaaanyyyyyyyy

Comment: without context this is not decidable. might mean more than one character repeated, *programee* vs *manyyyy*, or various different repetitions for the one word in the same document.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, but I think mayne the repetition  of words doesn't fit here, it could be more a stylistic feature (or both?).